# How to limit Content-Type header in Amazon s3 Pre-Signed Url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a client incorrectly setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` when uploading a pdf file to s3. This results in the client library we use to download the file to give it the wrong extension, also happens when you download the file from the s3 console, even though it has `.pdf` as the suffix, it downloads to `.json`.

Is there anyway to prevent clients from doing this? The Content type should always be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from my understanding.

Comment: Did you try adding bucket policy to restrict access to upload pdf file only?

Comment: There can be other file types, not just pdfs, I don’t necessarily know all of them ahead of time.